# Save Multiple Dropdowns Selections from a Table - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, save, html-table, dropdown

I have a Table with a column with Drop-down Selections. How do I save the selected choices on Save Button Click to my database.

I tried the following but I cant seem to get any data into the Array :

TABLE DISPLAY

[image: Drowdowns In Table]

DROPDOWN IN TABLE :

```
<td width="10%" nowrap> 

<select class="bs-select form-control" name="providers[]"     id="serviceProviders" data-id="<?php echo $row["provider_id"]; ?>" id="serviceProvider" data-live-search="true" data-size="8">    
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT PART

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveChanges', function(e){

            var id = []; 

            $('serviceProviders').each(function(i){  

                 id[i] = $(this).val();  

                   console.log('Service Provider Values are  = ' + id[i]);
            });  
            if(id.length === 0) //tell you if the array is empty  
            {  
                 alert("Please Select at least one transaction");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 $.ajax({  
                      url:'some_php_scrip_to_save_the_data.php',  
                      method:'POST',  
                      data:{id:id},  
                      success:function()  
                      {  
                           for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++)  
                           {  
                               // $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');  
                               // $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');  

                               window.location.reload(true); 

                           }  
                      }  
                 });  
            }  


  });
```

Comment: You should try multi-select for this.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Ids must be unique within an HTML document, you can not use the same id on multiple elements. And `$('serviceProviders')` would select elements with tha _tag name_ `serviceProviders`, of which there are none.

Comment: Try this <select class="bs-select form-control" name="providers[]"     id="serviceProviders" data-id="<?php echo $row["provider_id"]; ?>" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" multiple>. And don't use id="" more than one time in one tag.

Comment: Ok. If I differentiate the Ids.. how do I then put the different values in an array since the Drowpdowns are auto-generated and can have different Ids each time the Page Loads.. How do I cater for this in my JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute of an element must be unique. $('serviceProviders') should return you only one select element. Try suffixing the column number to the id inorder to make it unique.

```js
var id = []
for (var i = 1; i <= MaxColNo; i++) {
  var e = document.getElementById("serviceprovider" + i);
  var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  id[i] = text;
}
```

And in ajax call surround property name with quotes -  data :{'id':id}